# ¿Por qué la función filter de dplyr no funciona al agregar una segunda condición?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-dplyr

Saludos querida comunidad de programadores, mi consulta es la siguiente; tengo un dataframe de 7 variables y 16 observaciones que tiene como nombre "lluvia" (adjunto Imagen 1):

[image: Imagen 1]

mi propósito es realizar lo siguiente:

```
  lluvia %>%
          filter(lat == -19.25, lon == -63.05)
```

Lo cuál da como resultado "No data available in the table"

Pero al hacer lo siguiente:

```
  lluvia %>%
          filter(lat == -19.25)
```

Da como resultado solo las filas con lat = -19.25, es decir, funciona al imponer solamente una condición para filtrar pero no funciona con dos condiciones. Y como se puede ver en la imagen 1 si hay una fila  que cumple con la condición lat = -19.25 y lon = -63.05

Comment: ¿Has probado hacer `filter(long == -63.05)`? ¿funciona?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ahora lo he probabo `lluvia >%>% filter(lon == -63.05)`       y no funciona. Arroja como respuesta No data available in table. Lo que si funciona es por ejemplo al probar  `lluvia %>% filter(coords == "-19.35-62.85") ` ¿Será que la variable lon está presentando algún problema?

Comment: Revisa los datos, por que hay algo con la longitud que no es consistente con el filtro que estás intentando (no es un problema de combinar ambos), ¿habrá más decimales de los que se muestran? ¿la columna será un factor y no un numérico?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si, definitivamente es un problema de la variable lon, porque lo siguiente funciona : `lluvia >%>% filter(lon == -63.05, coords == "-19.25-63.05")`. las variables lat y lon son de tipo numerico, a ambas las creé como secuencia (seq) y luego las agregué al dataframe con cbind.
                                                              
`str(lluvia)
 data.frame': 42 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ lat          : num  -19 -19 -19 -19 -19 ...
 $ lon          : num  -63 -62.9 -62.8 -62.7 -62.6`

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en la función que tienes te falta agregar "&" donde simboliza "Y", y debido a esta razón te puede generar el problema, entonces en el siguiente código se muestra como debe escribirse correctamente:

```
filter(lluvia, lat == -19.25 &  lon == -63.05)
```

tal vez te funcione.

Comment: Saludos, ésto  parece ser más un comentario que una respuesta, te invito a revisar la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para poder proporcionar información que ayude tanto al miembro que pregunta como a los miembros que revisan las publicaciones, sigue adelante ;).

Comment: Para complementar tu respuesta, podrías agregar una explicación de que estaba mal. También mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: No, esto no es el problema, ya que la la concatenación de filtros separados por coma, ya funciona como un `&`

Answer (score 0):

A continuación, crearé dos vectores:

```
vector_1 <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 10)/100
vector_2 <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1)
```

Para nosotros, como humanos viviendo y pensando en un sistema decimal, hacer una comparación entre los valores de esos dos vectores debería resultar en un vector de SOLAMENTE valores `TRUE`. Pero si lo intentas hacer en R, obtendrás algo diferente (un vector con varios valores `FALSE`).

```
# Los valores lucen igual...
print(vector_1)
print(vector_2)

# ...pero no lo son     
vector_1 == vector_2
```

¿La razón? Aritmética de punto flotante, una característica de cómo funcionan las computadoras (en binario). No hay forma de que intente explicar eso acá, pero te dejo un link de lo que significa https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

¿Solución? Varias: algunas más elegantes que otras. Hubiera sido ideal que pusieras un ejemplo reproducible de tu tabla, pero algo que podrías hacer sería crear una columna de tipo caracter en donde pegues los valores de las columnas lon y lat y luego filtres según lo que quieras.

```
lluvia %>% 
  
  mutate(lon_lat = paste(lon, lat, sep = "_")) %>% 
  
  filter(lon_lat == "-19.25_-63.05")
```

No es una solución elegante, pero puede ser útil, sobre todo ahora que te has dado cuenta que, si bien te ha estado funcionando con `lon == -19.25`, eso no quiere decir que te funcione con otros valores de `lon` (y espero que lo hayas notado a tiempo: «Los peores errores en R son aquellos que no muestran mensajes de error»).